# Complexity of Maze problem if solution exist(Backtracking algorithm applied)

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, recursive-backtracking

Here is the solution: Using recursion tree method, looks like it should be exponential i.e 4 power n. But solving it is not clear. Like how one would describe in an interview. Any help is appreciated.

```
class Solution {
    public static boolean hasPath(int[][] maze, int[] start, int[] destination) {
        boolean result = false;
        result = moveNext(maze, start[0], start[1], destination);
        return result;
    }
    public static boolean moveNext(int[][] graph, int i, int j, int[] destination) {
        if (i < 0 || i == graph.length ||
                j < 0 || j == graph[0].length ||
                graph[i][j] == 1)
           return false;
        graph[i][j] = 1;
        if (i == destination[0] && j == destination[1])
           return true;

        return moveNext(graph, i, j + 1, destination)
               || moveNext(graph, i + 1, j, destination)
               || moveNext(graph, i, j - 1, destination) 
               || moveNext(graph, i - 1, j, destination);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] maze = {
            { 0, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 1, 0, 1, 1 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };
        int start[] = { 0, 0 };
        int destination[] = { 3, 3 };
        System.out.println(hasPath(maze, start, destination));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not exponential, it does not terminate on some cases. Try empty 3x3 or 4x4 maze with `start = { 2, 2 }`, and `end = { 0, 0 }`. The solution may revisit the same cell multiple times and loop.

Comment: it would terminate as soon as the destination coordinate matches with the current node co-ordinate. every node is set to 1 once visited to avoid the loop.  Also, my question was more in general, not case specific.

Comment: I believe it would never reach the destination coordinate on my example, it will just go between `(2, 2)` and `(2, 1)` in a loop. Asking about computation complexity of a non-terminating algorithm is pointless.

Comment: I think you're missing something. I tested your specific case. it works! coz when it goes back to 2,2 it would see it is already set to 1 so return false and then execute the other moveNext call.

Comment: I see, makes sense, missed that line. Then time complexity is proportional to the area of the maze.

Comment: It's basically [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: Yeah that make sense. DFS is backtracking essentially. But to explain and verify how should i make the recurrence relation for it to prove its complexity is O(m*n)

Comment: Also, what would be the space complexity for this and why?